# Shared Preferences never loads in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have like 36 buttons (i am showing only 2 in this question) in activity **Pim**. each button assigns/saves a key in my shared preferences which are loaded in the activity **S1m** but the problem is it never loads my keys.

**P1m**

```
public class P1m extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.durations);
    }

    public void ten(View view) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Plan saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("train", "p1m_10");
        editor.commit();
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void fifteen(View view) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Plan saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("train", "p1m_15");
        editor.commit();
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**S1m**

```
public class S1m extends Activity implements IBaseGpsListener {
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        timer.cancel();
    }

    private TextView q;
    private CountDownTimer timer;
    private Vibrator mVibrator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sprint_ui);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, this);
        this.updateSpeed(null);

        CheckBox chkUseMetricUntis = (CheckBox) this
                .findViewById(R.id.chkMetricUnits);
        chkUseMetricUntis
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        S1m.this.updateSpeed(null);
                    }
                });

        // LOAD SHARED PREF P1m////////////////////////////////////////////

        SharedPreferences preferences11 = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name2 = preferences11.getString("train", "");

        if (name2.equals("p1m_10")) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                private Vibrator mVibrator;

                public void run() {
                    mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    mVibrator.vibrate(1000 * 10);// sprint time vibration
                    // HANDLER
                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // calculate result1
                            TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentSpeed);
                            String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();
                            TextView theFact1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result1);
                            theFact1.setText(String.valueOf(shareFact));
                            // calculate result1
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3333);
                    // HANDLER END //
                    // HANDLER
                    Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // calculate result2
                            TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentSpeed);
                            String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();
                            TextView theFact1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result2);
                            theFact1.setText(String.valueOf(shareFact));
                            // calculate result2
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable1, 6666);
                    // HANDLER END //
                    // HANDLER
                    Runnable runnable11 = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // calculate result3
                            TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentSpeed);
                            String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();
                            TextView theFact1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result3);
                            theFact1.setText(String.valueOf(shareFact));
                            // calculate result3
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable11, 9999);
                    // HANDLER END //
                    // warning
                    Runnable runnable111 = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getBaseContext(),
                                    "*you have 5 seconds left. get ready for the next sprint!*",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            mVibrator.vibrate(1000);
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable111, 10000 + 60000 - 5000);// warning
                                                                            // after
                    // warning //
                }
            }, 5999, 10000 + 60000);// repeat after (+5.999s first run delay)

        } else if (name2.equals("p1m_15")) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                private Vibrator mVibrator;

                public void run() {
                    mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    mVibrator.vibrate(1000 * 15);// sprint time vibration
                    // HANDLER
                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // calculate result1
                            TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentSpeed);
                            String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();
                            TextView theFact1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result1);
                            theFact1.setText(String.valueOf(shareFact));
                            // calculate result1
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
                    // HANDLER END //
                    // HANDLER
                    Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // calculate result2
                            TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentSpeed);
                            String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();
                            TextView theFact1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result2);
                            theFact1.setText(String.valueOf(shareFact));
                            // calculate result2
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable1, 10000);
                    // HANDLER END //
                    // HANDLER
                    Runnable runnable11 = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // calculate result3
                            TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentSpeed);
                            String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();
                            TextView theFact1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result3);
                            theFact1.setText(String.valueOf(shareFact));
                            // calculate result3
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable11, 15000);
                    // HANDLER END //
                    // warning
                    Runnable runnable111 = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getBaseContext(),
                                    "*you have 5 seconds left. get ready for the next sprint!*",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            mVibrator.vibrate(1000);
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable111, 15000 + 60000 - 5000);// warning
                                                                            // after
                    // warning //
                }
            }, 5999, 15000 + 60000);// repeat after (+5.999s first run delay)

            // LOAD SHARED PREF P1m////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
    }

    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void updateSpeed(CLocation location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float nCurrentSpeed = 0;

        if (location != null) {
            location.setUseMetricunits(this.useMetricUnits());
            nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
        }

        Formatter fmt = new Formatter(new StringBuilder());
        fmt.format(Locale.US, "%5.1f", nCurrentSpeed);
        String strCurrentSpeed = fmt.toString();
        strCurrentSpeed = strCurrentSpeed.replace(' ', '0');

        String strUnits = "miles/hour";
        if (this.useMetricUnits()) {
            strUnits = "meters/second";
        }

        TextView txtCurrentSpeed = (TextView) this
                .findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentSpeed);
        txtCurrentSpeed.setText(strCurrentSpeed + " " + strUnits);
    }

    private boolean useMetricUnits() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CheckBox chkUseMetricUnits = (CheckBox) this
                .findViewById(R.id.chkMetricUnits);
        return chkUseMetricUnits.isChecked();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (location != null) {
            CLocation myLocation = new CLocation(location,
                    this.useMetricUnits());
            this.updateSpeed(myLocation);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

my buttons are working fine because the always show the Toast they are assigned.

Comment: In P1m , you are creating the SharedPreferences instant variable every time when the button is created . Create the SharedPreferences and Editor variable only once during onCreate() and use them in the onClick() method to assign the key-value pair.

Comment: @adhithiyan it didnt work

Comment: you will be surprised i'm using the same codes in my other activities (P15, S15) and it is working fine i just copy pasted code in all of them. its working fine for p15, p20, p30 but not for p1m, p2m, p3m, p5m and p7m

Answer (score 0):

For Better Code , Create Constant File and use from the Constant file as you needed in your java class , like following.

```
public class Constants {

    public static SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

}
```

Your P1m Class

```
public class P1m extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.durations);
}

public void ten(View view) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Plan saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    Constants.prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs",  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Constants.editor = Constants.prefs.edit();

    Constants.editor.putString("train", "p1m_10");
    Constants.editor.commit();

    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void fifteen(View view) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Plan saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    Constants.editor.putString("train", "p1m_15");
    Constants.editor.commit();
    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

In your S1m class , get value like follwoing way ,

```
 Constants.prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs",    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 Constants.editor = Constants.prefs.edit();
 String train = Constants.prefs.getString("train", "your default train");
```

After this you successfully get your value and got improvement in your code.

Comment: Hello @Toxic Got solution or not ?

Comment: tryed as my answeres ?

Comment: you also check that your all button contain this properties or not **android:onClick="yourmethod"**